# How does a three-way light switch work?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, multiway-switch

A three-way light switch allows the light to be controlled from two locations. How does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be some confusion because the type of switch you need (*single-pole, double-throw*) is [usually called a *three-way switch* in the US, and a *two-way switch* in the UK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_terminology). So for two switches to control the same lights, you need two SPDT switches, and you can find the wiring diagram [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching#Two_locations).

Answer (score 0):

Between the two switches is another cable wire connecting both switches. then they both work like train track switches alternating the on/off current to the fixture.