# What are the pros and cons of different types of smart switches on the UK market? 

Tags: electrical, home-automation

When putting in a new switch for a light, it is often less work to put in a smart switch than run the mains cables.

However how do you choose the type of smart switch to use?

---

See Also "[What are the pros and cons of different types of smart switches (That are on the **USA** market)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-different-types-of-smart-switches-that-are-on-the)?"

Comment: This question should be Community Wiki as there will not be one right answer, and you're asking for a list.

Comment: This question is 2 years old and has no answers. [The USA market question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-different-types-of-smart-switches-that-are-on-the) has several quality answers. Most of the technologies mentioned there are available worldwide, and only the brands and distributors will vary. See that one if you find yourself asking this question.