# What hardware do I need to have a wireless light switch in UK/Ireland?

Tags: lighting, wiring

Builders are converting my attic at the moment and stupidly, the electrician only installed the light switch for the attic at the bottom of the stairwell so there's no actual light switch in the room.

It's too late to rewire as the new floor has been installed and the walls finished so my only real option is to have a wireless light switch in the room with some sort of receiver in the stairwell. And optionally the wired light switch in the stairwell could be replaced with another wireless light switch as I still need the lights to be operated from both the room and the stairwell.

I'm brand agnostic but what exactly do I need?

There seems to be lots of hardware available to automate absolutely everything in the house but I'd like a simple recommendation for setting up a remote controlled light switch (with two way control)!

And are there any potential wiring complications with installing the receiver?

Comment: Unfortunate that [What are the pros and cons of different types of smart switches (That are on the UK maket)?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-different-types-of-smart-switches-that-are-on-the) was never answered, as it is one way that would work.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple with simple search for "3-way wireless switch", 
[Leviton 6696-W Wireless 3-Way Decora-Style Switch Kit](http://www.smarthome.com/2531W/Leviton-6696-W-Wireless-3-Way-Decora-Style-Switch-Kit-White/p.aspx)

[image]

and [BL-6133-WH Wireless Add-On Switch Set](http://www.heath-zenith.com/prod_details.cgi?file=3.2.348).

[image]

Unfortunately, both are listed for 120V. Though, I'm sure there is something similar available in your area (which I'm assuming is 220V).

For the two I found, installation is simple. Swap out the existing switch with the receiver switch, then install the transmitter switch wherever you need it.

Comment: Yes, I need 220V appliances so the ones you suggest are not suitable but I have more to go on now. Thanks.