# How do I remove a 3-way switch?

Tags: electrical

I am taking a non bearing wall down that has electrical work in it, including a 3 way switch for a single light. I want to disconnect this switch so the other one works. How do I do this?

Comment: It depends.   Where is the power coming from, and where is the fixture?

Comment: Please post photographs of the wiring at each of the switches, and -- if you can trace the wiring -- a schematic of the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to trace the wires.
You can look at [How exactly does a 3-way switch work?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/how-exactly-does-a-3-way-switch-work).
You should replace the remaining 3 way with a regular single switch and wire it normally to the light fixture.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  You might be lucky or not, depends on which way the wires go.
Note that any any splices in wires must be accessible for future work.

Start with https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/4054/5960 and post some photos.

Comment: Define "abandon wires in the wall" please - one of the worst things one could do would be to leave hot wires in the wall.

Comment: Abandoning a traveler in the wall is OK: he has access to both sides. There's not enough detail in the question to really outline the options.  The OP has not come back, so there's little incentive to give a full answer.